# How to set Column Priority in Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo grid and I've Columns array like below

```
 columns: [
            {
                field: "Column1",
                title: "Column 1",
                width: "120px"
            },
            {
                field: "Column2",
                title: "Column 2",
                width: "120px"
            },
            {
                field: "Column3",
                title: "Column 3",
                width: "160px"
            },
            .
            .
            .
          ]
```

How to set the order of the columns display in kendo grid or Is it possible any other way? Like 1st Column2 and  then Column3 and then Column1 need to be displayed.

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: Do you want to set the order only during the grid's initialization or do you want the ability to set the order dynamically using code later as well?

Comment: Dynamically using code later @Shai

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `reorderColumn(destIndex, object)` event: [reorderColumn](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/reordercolumn#reordercolumn).

> 1. **destIndex** `Number` The new position of the column. The destination index
>    should be calculated with regard to all columns, including the hidden
>    ones.

> 2. **column** `Object` The column whose position should be changed.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
      { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ]
});
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

//your logic for calcualting destination index and column
grid.reorderColumn(1, grid.columns[0]);
```

Offical example: [reorderColumn](https://dojo.telerik.com/aqelusiK)

Comment: It's just like swapping of two columns. If it's swapping of more columns it'd be more complex.

Comment: Then create new columns array and set it in grid options. Or loop through existing columns and reorder it. You didn't provide any case just: "Like 1st Column2 and then Column3 and then Column1 need to be displayed"